# [Py]Spark SQL: Multi-column sessionization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a positive Long `i` and a DataFrame

```
+-----+--+--+                                                          
|group|n1|n2|                                                              
+-----+--+--+                                                              
|    1| 0| 0|                                                              
|    1| 1| 1|                                                              
|    1| 1| 5|                                                              
|    1| 2| 2|                                                              
|    1| 2| 6|                                                              
|    1| 3| 3|                                                              
|    1| 3| 7|                                                              
|    1| 4| 4|                                                              
|    1| 5| 1|                                                              
|    1| 5| 5|                                                              
+-----+--+--+
```

how would you [sessionize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(web_analytics)) rows in the same `group` such that for each pair of consecutive rows `r1`, `r2` in a session, `r2.n1` > `r1.n1`, `r2.n2` > `r1.n2`, and max(`r2.n1` - `r1.n1`, `r2.n2` - `r1.n2`) < `i`? Note, `n1` and `n2` values may not be unique, meaning rows that make up a session may not be consecutive in the DataFrame.

As an example, the result for the given DataFrame and `i`=3 would be

```
+-----+--+--+-------+
|group|n1|n2|session|
+-----+--+--+-------+
|    1| 0| 0|      1|
|    1| 1| 1|      1|
|    1| 1| 5|      2|
|    1| 2| 2|      1|
|    1| 2| 6|      2|
|    1| 3| 3|      1|
|    1| 3| 7|      2|
|    1| 4| 4|      1|
|    1| 5| 1|      3|
|    1| 5| 5|      1|
+-----+--+--+-------+
```

Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you're trying to mark with a same number all connected parts of a graph. A good solution would be to use `graphframes`: https://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html

From your dataframe:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 5],[1, 2, 2],[1, 2, 6],
                    [1, 3, 3],[1, 3, 7],[1, 4, 4],[1, 5, 1],[1, 5, 5]]).toDF(["group","n1","n2"])
```

We'll create a vertex dataframe containing the list of unique `id`s:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
v = df.select(psf.struct("n1", "n2").alias("id"), "group")

    +-----+-----+
    |   id|group|
    +-----+-----+
    |[0,0]|    1|
    |[1,1]|    1|
    |[1,5]|    1|
    |[2,2]|    1|
    |[2,6]|    1|
    |[3,3]|    1|
    |[3,7]|    1|
    |[4,4]|    1|
    |[5,1]|    1|
    |[5,5]|    1|
    +-----+-----+
```

And an edge dataframe defined from the boolean condition you stated:

```py
i = 3
e = df.alias("r1").join(
    df.alias("r2"), 
    (psf.col("r1.group") == psf.col("r2.group"))
    & (psf.col("r1.n1") < psf.col("r2.n1"))
    & (psf.col("r1.n2") < psf.col("r2.n2"))
    & (psf.greatest(
        psf.col("r2.n1") - psf.col("r1.n1"),
        psf.col("r2.n2") - psf.col("r1.n2")) < i)
).select(psf.struct("r1.n1", "r1.n2").alias("src"), psf.struct("r2.n1", "r2.n2").alias("dst"))

    +-----+-----+
    |  src|  dst|
    +-----+-----+
    |[0,0]|[1,1]|
    |[0,0]|[2,2]|
    |[1,1]|[2,2]|
    |[1,1]|[3,3]|
    |[1,5]|[2,6]|
    |[1,5]|[3,7]|
    |[2,2]|[3,3]|
    |[2,2]|[4,4]|
    |[2,6]|[3,7]|
    |[3,3]|[4,4]|
    |[3,3]|[5,5]|
    |[4,4]|[5,5]|
    +-----+-----+
```

And now to find all connected components:

```py
from graphframes import *
g = GraphFrame(v, e)
res = g.connectedComponents()

    +-----+-----+------------+
    |   id|group|   component|
    +-----+-----+------------+
    |[0,0]|    1|309237645312|
    |[1,1]|    1|309237645312|
    |[1,5]|    1| 85899345920|
    |[2,2]|    1|309237645312|
    |[2,6]|    1| 85899345920|
    |[3,3]|    1|309237645312|
    |[3,7]|    1| 85899345920|
    |[4,4]|    1|309237645312|
    |[5,1]|    1|292057776128|
    |[5,5]|    1|309237645312|
    +-----+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marie. Finding the connected components did the trick! Unfortunately, the performance is terrible - it took more than a minute to find the solution for the example I provided! Do you know why this might be?

Comment: It iterates as many times as the maximum branch length. You can try tuning your graph so it works faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, even with graph tuning, the poor run-time performance is a deal-breaker on my production data set.